# Current date and time in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

I want a SQL query to show the current date and time.

I have tried

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;   --"FROM keyword not found where expected"
SELECT GETDATE();           --"FROM keyword not found where expected"
SELECT GETUTCDATE();        --"FROM keyword not found where expected"
NOW();                      -- Error report - Unknown Command
```

But none of them worked.

Requesting your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Add `FROM DUAL;`. Oracle wants a `FROM` clause for each `SELECT`, the ANSI SQL way.

Comment: Invalid identifier error

Comment: Please try SELECT  SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 2):

Oracle supports ANSI standard variables CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_DATE with mandatory FROM clause -

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL;
```

Alternatively, You can use Oracle specific date variable SYSDATE also -

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/v1ASiFJr)

Comment: ANSI SQL's LOCALTIMESTAMP is also supported.

Comment: _The difference between this function and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is that LOCALTIMESTAMP returns a TIMESTAMP value while CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value._

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to handle the format of date/time fetched. For that you can use To_Char() function. Some of the options are:

```sql
Select
      SYSDATE "DB_FORMAT_DATE",
      To_Char(SYSDATE, 'dd-Month yyyy') "DATE_FORMAT_1",
      To_Char(SYSDATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy') "DATE_FORMAT_1",
      To_Char(SYSDATE, 'hh:mi:ss am') "TIME_FORMAT_1",
      To_Char(SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') "TIME_FORMAT_2",
      To_Char(SYSDATE, 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "DATETIME_FORMAT_ANY"
From Dual

DB_FORMAT_DATE DATE_FORMAT_1     DATE_FORMAT_1 TIME_FORMAT_1 TIME_FORMAT_2 DATETIME_FORMAT_ANY
-------------- ----------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- --------------------
02-FEB-23      02-February 2023  02.02.2023    04:29:30 PM   16:29:30      02-Feb-2023 16:29:30
```

More about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions165.htm).